# Can the application model contribute parts to e3.x application GUI which is built on top of e4

Tags: eclipse

Looking to contribute parts and part stack to an already existing 3.x GUI built on top of e4 via Application Model(e4xmi)

Comment: There is very little documentation on doing this. It is a lot easier to stick to the 3.x API

Comment: Thanks greg your posts are very helpful. I appreciate you response